# Methods for pasting together dates from day, month, year

Tags: r

I have using quite a large dataset (30+ million IDs) that provides columns for the date of an event:

```
df<- data.frame(id=c("A", "B", "C"), year=c("1955", "1967", "1944"), 
                  month= c("1", "2", "3"), day=c("1", "2", "3")
```

I want to piece these together to form a date. I have been using the following method

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df$date <- paste(df$day, df$month, df$year, sep="-") %>% dmy()
```

Are there any other ways to do this?

I ask because this appears computationally quite taxing and I cant perform it even if I increase my memory limits.

Comment: “this appears computationally quite taxing” — That’s very unlikely. The issue is more likely elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

since you already loaded `lubridate` and the `tidyverse`, try

```
df %>% mutate(date = make_date(year, month, day))

#   id year month day       date
# 1  A 1955     1   1 1955-01-01
# 2  B 1967     2   2 1967-02-02
# 3  C 1944     3   3 1944-03-03
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `ISOdate`

```
df$date <- with(df, as.Date(ISOdate(year, month, day)))
df$date
#[1] "1955-01-01" "1967-02-02" "1944-03-03"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `unite` function from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  unite(date, c("year", "month", "day"), sep = "-", remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date))

  id       date year month day
1  A 1955-01-01 1955     1   1
2  B 1967-02-02 1967     2   2
3  C 1944-03-03 1944     3   3
```